# Fstream reads some strange numbers and causes segfault

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to get this code working, but it is causing an instant segfault and i don't know why. Fstream can open files, but those three while loops are causing problems - program doesnt throw segfault if I comment them. Of course array capacity is larger than files. When I use cout << inputf it shows something like 0x7fff617291a0, but files seem to be ok, so I'm a bit counfused.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main(){

string plikf = "BH_diagnostics.ah1.pg";
string pliks = "BH_diagnostics.ah2.pg";
string plikt = "BH_diagnostics.ah3.pg";
ifstream inputf("BH1"); ifstream inputs("BH2"); ifstream inputt("BH3");
ofstream output("script.p");;

output << "plot " << '"' << plikf << '"' << "using 1:2, " << '"' << pliks << '"' << "using 1:2, " << '"' << plikt << '"' << "using 1:2 w l \n";
double trash;

if(!inputf) cout << "panick 1 ";
if(!inputs) cout << "panick 2 ";
if(!inputt) cout << "panick 3" ;

double bhf[3000][5];
double bhs[3000][5];
double bht[3000][5];
int i,j,k;
// PROBLEM HERE
while (inputf >> trash >> bhf[i][0] >> bhf[i][1] >> bhf[i][2] >> bhf[i][3] >> trash >> trash >> bhf[i][4] >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash){i++;cout << bhf[i][0];} 
while (inputs >> trash >> bhs[j][0] >> bhs[j][1] >> bhs[j][2] >> bhs[j][3] >> trash >> trash >> bhs[j][4] >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash){ j++; cout << bhs[j][0];}
while ( inputt >> trash >> bht[k][0] >> bht[k][1] >> bht[k][2] >> bht[k][3] >> trash >> trash >> bht[k][4] >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash  >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash ){ k++; cout << bht[k][0];}


int l,n;
double dt = bht[k][0]/20;
for (int s=0; s<i; s++) {
if (bhf[s][0] > l) { output << "\n set object " << n << " circle at axis " << bhf[s][1] << ',' << bhf[s][2] << " size first " << bhf[s][4] <<  " fc rgb " << '"' << "navy" << '"' << "\n"; l+=dt; n++;}
}

l=bhs[1][0];

for (int s=0; s<j; s++) {
if (bhs[s][0] > l) { output << "\n set object " << n << " circle at axis " << bhs[s][1] << ',' << bhs[s][2] << " size first " << bhs[s][4] <<  " fc rgb " << '"' << "navy" << '"' << "\n"; l+=dt; n++;}
}

l=bht[1][0];

for (int s=0; s<k; s++) {
if (bht[s][0] > l) { output << "\n set object " << n << " circle at axis " << bht[s][1] << ',' << bht[s][2] << " size first " << bht[s][4] <<  " fc rgb " << '"' << "navy" << '"' << "\n"; l+=dt; n++;}
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: First off I'd split those up into readable and *checkable* chunks - what if some part fails for some reason? Next have you checked array bounds? OH and i,j,k are unititialised....

Comment: int i,j,k are not initialized before use.

Comment: `i` isn't initialized, man......

Comment: also you should read some coding guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, that your loop variables (i, j, k) are not initialized and contain random values. Accessing your array with those values then causes your segfault.

```
int i = 0; 
int j = 0; 
int k = 0;
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,j,k;
```

should be initialised to 0 or some start condition. They will contain random values this way and therefore probably cause a bounds issue with the loop accessing your arrays.

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
```